# Installing Laravel on Windows 11 via Curl issue: ambiguous redirect

Tags: bash, docker, curl, laravel-sail

I'm trying to install Laravel via Curl for the use of Laravel Sail with docker like this

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

But I get this error

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                   Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   947    0   947    0     0    947      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1835
: ambiguous redirect
-bash: line 2: $'\r': command not found
-bash: line 35: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Why am I getting this and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you running the command on WSL terminal? Ref.: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-windows

Comment: windows powershell terminal

Comment: I used the default CMD and it started downloading but when it comes to asking to enter the password it doesn't do anything and when I press CTRL+C I find out that it was trying to execute the password as a command

Comment: Looking at the script you're trying to execute, it seems more like you should run it from WSL than Windows: https://laravel.build/example-app

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows) , you must use that command line in the Windows Terminal beginning a new terminal session for your WSL2 Linux operating system.

And [here](https://medium.com/@awlucattini_60867/getting-started-with-wsl2-c11826654776) you can find how to set Ubuntu as the default profile of Windows Terminal.

This helps me a lot.

Comment: This helped me solved the related issue I encountered. If you want to put the project in your windows drive (C or D), just use the "cd /mnt/yourWindowsDrive/theDirectory/theDirectory/".